# Codeception - WebDriverCurlException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception

I just started using Codeception, I'm trying to use WebDriver, but I keep getting this error message "Curl error thrown for http POST to http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox"}}
  couldn't connect to host". I've started server with
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar. 
I'm running Codeception on Vagrant. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you selenium server is running in the host machine, it normally should start listening to any network interface by default.

What is happening is that from within the guest VM (Vagrant in your case) you need to specify the address of the host machine, which in virtualbox is usually 192.168.56.1. Have a look at the address of the gateway in the guest machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a solution :)